# Testing for Enum and a String - .NET Core 3.1 and xUnit

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, xunit

I am new to TDD and I have a method that takes an `Enum` and a `string`.  After doing some reading, I found that testing an `Enum` is not really worth doing unless you have some methods in the `Enum` class (please correct me if I am wrong).

My other methods that I am testing are simple and take in a `string` which I check for `null` or `empty`, but when I came to this method I was unsure what to do.

```
public string CreateLog(LoggerLevel level, string message)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Here is the `Enum`

```
public enum LoggerLevel
{
    Verbose,
    Debug,
    Information,
    Warning,
    Error,
    Fatal
}
```

Here is how I was intending on handling the `string` but what is the best way to handle the expected `enum` in the `CreateLog` method:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateLog_MessageNullOrEmpty()
{
    var logger = new Logger();

    Assert.Throws<MessageNullOrEmptyException>(() => logger.CreateLog(enum???, null));

    Assert.Throws<MessageNullOrEmptyException>(() => logger.CreateLog(enum???, ""));
}
```

I was thinking of using the `[InlineData(LoggerLevel.Verbose), ""]` and `[InlineData(LoggerLevel.Debug), null]`.  Or creating a dummy `enum` in the test method and passing that in.

What is the best way to tackle this scenario?

Comment: In these scenarios I usually add an `Unknown` or `None` value to my `enum` as the first value. That way if it's created but not assigned to, it doesn't fall back to some invalid value (in this cases `Verbose`). If it's not set or doesn't need to be set, then it should be described as so. If you can't edit the enum, then just set it to some arbitrary value since in this case it has no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood very well, but If in above test just string is matters, you can mock enum with `It.IsAny<T>`, from [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) package.

by the way, Enum parameter never will be null if you don't define like Nullable.